# Is there an alternative to image map to be able to change background-color of a specifif div area on an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint

I tried with image map combine with the Jquery Tool maphilight.js and it work all fine on desktop but when I tried to deploy the html page in a Content Editor Webpart on Sharepoint Onpremise, it doesn't work.

I tried to put the code in a Script Editor Webpart without any success.

There is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.maphilight.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.map').maphilight();
    });</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <img src="./images/canada.png" class="map" usemap="#simple">
    <map name="simple">
        <area coords="542,313,573,365,590,372,608,370,621,372,636,365,670,359,675,341,670,321,677,306,690,295,698,282,703,257,700,229,672,241,662,252,649,262,634,257,619,252,606,239,619,231,608,216,593,203,573,188,575,208,560,213,552,213,544,206,534,198,524,200,506,193,493,200,481,200,498,226,498,239,514,241,527,249,527,277,521,285,532,298" shape="poly" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"4d738e","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"4d738e","fillOpacity":0.5}'>
    </map>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Like I sad it work very well on my desktop but not on sharepoint on premise.
And yes i have changed the path of img and js library for the good one on the SP version.

Is there any alternative I can do with css or any other plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Screenshot :

[image: Exemple]

Answer (score 0):

Add the example code below into script editor web part in site page to check if it works.

```
<div>
    <img src="https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/0*H8odJZNPmo13lEJ2" class="map" width="800" usemap="#simple"/>
    <map name="simple">
        <area coords="211,259,192,300,212,337,208,414,228,425,243,418,274,363,307,305,291,292,272,284,231,254" shape="poly" data-maphilight='{"strokeColor":"4d738e","strokeWidth":5,"fillColor":"4d738e","fillOpacity":0.5}'>
    </map>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maphilight/1.4.0/jquery.maphilight.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.map').maphilight();
    });
</script>
```

[image]

And using IE F12 developer tools to check if some js error occurs, and check the CSS styles.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work, and there is no js or css error in dev tool.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work.

There is an error with maphilight.js don't know what it mean.

There's a screenshot :

[image]